# vertical dropdown menu active class for submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

There is a class active, when I use it for parent menu it just highlights.
I want the submenus are opened when i use like `<li class='has-sub active'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a> ...`

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0zqtafjr/)

My Script:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
        $('#cssmenu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
        $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
            $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }
            if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: it is opening submenu, what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

Add this

```
$('#cssmenu .active ul').show();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zqtafjr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger click event on the active li.

Add

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a').trigger('click');
```

at the end of the script. just outside of the click event.